# How to get MongoDB connection object in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, mongodb, pymongo, djongo

I am using `djongo` as default engine.
I want to get the `MongoDB` connection object just like we get `mysql` object from

```
from django.db import connection
```

How can we do that in Django so that i can perform raw queries of MongoDB?

I know we can do this with `pymongo` but i will be good if i can do that with django itself.

Comment: Django doesn't have any native integration with Mongo, so your question is not answerable without more information.

Comment: But we can with djongo e.g. from djongo import models